# jQuery - Foundation Datepicker on 'changeDate' trigger not behaving well

Tags: jquery, django, forms, datepicker, zurb-foundation

Link to package/app/whatever you want to call it: http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html

So I have a form in my HTML file called `dp-form` and inside of it there is a text input called `dp` with attribute `name="datepicker"`. I know the datepicker and the form works because when I select a date and use a submit button, everything works as expected, however, I unfortunately got ambitious and decided to try and let the jQuery handle the posting and submitting leading me to the follow code at the end of my HTML file:

```
<script>
    $('#dp').fdatepicker(format='yyyy-mm-dd')
        .on('changeDate', function(event) {
               var pickedDate = $("#dp").val();

               $.ajaxSetup( {data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}} );
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/index/",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {'datepicker': pickedDate, 'routepicker': "default"}
                });
            });

    $("#dp-form").submit();
</script>
```

Problem is once I load up the containing page, it posts the data from an empty form (which has not been clicked on, date picker hasn't opened, nothing is done with at all) and submits it, and then keeps doing this. It is stuck in an infinite loop doing this and my page is constantly reloading since it keeps submitting empty data.

Comment: `fdatepicker(format='yyyy-mm-dd')` copy/paste error or `fdatepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' })`?

Comment: I did the former (without the brackets) and it was formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're submitting the form at each page load by writing this :

```
$("#dp-form").submit();
```

You should call this in the 'changeDate' event handler :

```
$('#dp').fdatepicker(format='yyyy-mm-dd')
        .on('changeDate', function(event) {
               var pickedDate = $("#dp").val();
               $("#dp-form").submit();
            });
```

If you want to send your form with ajax, you could use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

```
<html>
```

```
<script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#dp').fdatepicker(format='yyyy-mm-dd')
        .on('changeDate', function(event) {
               var pickedDate = $("#dp").val();
               $("#dp-form").submit();
            });
        // bind 'dp-form' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#dp-form').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for posting"); 
        }); 
    });
    //You'll also need this snippet in order to not struggle with csrftoken in Django :
    $(function() {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ...d'oh! Of course it was that simple haha. Quick follow up though: why do I need to use that snippet for CSRF tokens? What I had originally with `csrfmiddlewaretoken` appeared to be working.